# algorithm to compute a linear extension of partial order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Let $\preceq$ be a partial order on a finite set $X$. Is there an algorithm with time complexity $O(|X|^{2})$ which can compute a linear extension $\leq$ for the partial order $\preceq$ on $X$?

Comment: It would improve your Question to add a few words about how you became interested in this problem.  I am fond of the term [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for such algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your problem can be reduced to computing a topological ordering of a directed acyclic graph $D = (X, A)$, where $X$ is the finite set and there is an arc $\overrightarrow{xy}$ in $A$ iff $x \preceq y$. There is a simple $O(|X| + |A|)$-time algorithm to compute a topological ordering which can be found in most algorithms textbooks. See, for example, section 6.3 of [Erickson's book](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/).